# SQL Reporting Services Report with subreports showing as blank page

Tags: asp.net, sql, reporting-services

I do not have much experience with SQL Reporting Services, but I am maintaining a report that other users created.

They have 10 reports which all print fine on the development box and the production box.  They also have an "Entire Event" report that has all the other 10 reports as sub reports.  This shows any reports with data in them on the development box (any of the sub reports without data are suppressed, which is fine).  However on the production box it looks like every sub report is suppressed regardless of data.  The report just shows a header and a blank page.

Any thoughts of where I can start debugging.  The environments seem the same to me as far as I can tell.  If there was a serious difference between the two environment I would think that the individual reports wouldn't print either, but its just when they are sub reports that this happens.

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the subreport in the Visual Studio designer (The gray area is the subreport).This should have the visibility properties in it, which is where you set if the sub report is visible or not.

Also, within that same properties menu is the Parameters tab. Make sure all the parametrs are set properly. If the reports work individually, they should work in the larger report if everything is setup properly with visibilty and parameters.

You may also want to check in the general tab taht the sub report is pointing to the proper reports.